# Combining Google Maps (Basic Javascript Issue)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hoping someone can point out something really obvious here (I don't really know Javascript at all). Basically I have two maps, one which does Geocoding based on a an address passed over through PHP, and another which pulls a list of locations from a MySQL DB into an XML file.

Both maps work perfectly in isolation. I need to combine them however, so the one map marks the locations in the XML file, and also shows the Geocoded marker. The code of the two of these combined is below:

```
<script>
  var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
      label: 'R'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    }
  };

  var geocoder;
var address ="<?php
foreach ($records as $record)
{
    print htmlspecialchars($record['Address']);
}
?>";

 /// Start of XML Lookup Map

    function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
      zoom: 6
    });


    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('test.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};



          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });


          var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: 200000,    // 10 miles in metres
            fillColor: '#AA0000'
            });
            circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');





        });
      });
    }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}

  /// End of XML Lookup Map

  /// Start of Geocoding Map

  function initialize() {
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
 var myOptions = {
  zoom: 7,
  center: latlng,
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: 
google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
if (geocoder) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
              size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
            });

        var markerz = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map, 
            title:address
        }); 



    // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 200000,    // 10 miles in metres
      fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', markerz, 'position');


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, markerz, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

      } else {
        alert("No results found");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + 
status);
    }
  });
 }
}

  /// End of Geocoding Map

</script>
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: you initialize the map twice on the same canvas `map_canvas` afaik just add another canvas element with another id to your html markup and adjust your code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @John Smith, got this resolved. Posting the working code below. This will allow for lookup and pin of a Geocoded address, as well as pulling and pinning the lat/lng coords from an XML file through PHP, on the one map.

```
 <script>
  var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
      label: 'R'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    },
    stockingcenter: {
      label: 'S'
    }
  };

  var geocoder;
var address ="<?php
foreach ($records as $record)
{
print htmlspecialchars($record['Address__c']);
}
?>";

 /// Start of XML Lookup Map

    function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5477187, -0.3150843),
      zoom: 6
    });


    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('test.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
           marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          }); 


        });
      });




  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}

  /// End of XML Lookup Map


   /// Start of Geocoding Map


       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var myOptions = {
                         zoom: 6};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
     if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
               map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
              { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
              });

    var markerz = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: map, 
        title:address
    }); 



// Add circle overlay and bind to marker
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 200000,    // 10 miles in metres
  fillColor: '#4e63a1'
});
circle.bindTo('center', markerz, 'position');


    google.maps.event.addListener(markerz, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,markerz);
    });

  } else {
    alert("No results found");
  }
} else {
  alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + 
status);
}
});
}
}

/// End of Geocoding Map
</script>
```